# Doubts on LLDB debugging method

Tags: ios

In `LLDB debugger`, `self.property` works, but why doesn't `self.property.property` work.

example:

po `self.modelData.arrayOfChatMessages`

There is no member named `arrayOfChatMessages`.When a function from another class is stepped in and I try to do this:

`po self.anotherClass`'s property(The class in which the function that the debugger is stepped in is present) it gives the following message:

```
po self.anotherClassProperty
```

There is no member named `anotherClassProperty`. Can anyone please help me out.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a limitation of the debugger.  To work around it, use regular message syntax:

```
po [[self modelData] arrayOfChatMessages]
po [self anotherClassProperty]
```